# Calculated Column for Shift Start in PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am importing a report into Power Pivot.  The report has a Production Date (A1) and a Production Time (A2) column.  Shift change over is at 6:00 AM and 6:00 PM.  What formula in a calculated column can I use to get the shift start date?

*Power Pivot will not allow me to change the column to text.

[image]

Comment: `IF(OR(B2<.25, B2>=.75), A2+.75, A2+.25)`

Comment: @wbeard52 It works on some but not all.  10/17/10 at 2:19:00 should end up as 10/16/10 6 PM.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(B2<.25, A2-.25, IF(B2>=.75, A2+.75, A2+.25)`

### How it works

Time, in Excel, is represented as a fraction of a day.  The two columns are A and B are essentially a whole number in column A and a fractional number between 0 and 1 in column B.

It turns out that 6pm is exactly 75% of the way through the day.  Since time is calculated as a fraction of we can add 75% of a day or subtract 25% from the previous day.

---

If the time is less than 25% of the day or 6am, then the work day starts at 6pm the previous day.  `IF(B2<.25, A2-.25)`

If the time is greater than 75% of the day or 6pm, then the work day also starts at 6pm of the current day.  `If (B2>.75, A2+.75)`

If the time does not fall before 6am or after 6pm then the workday starts at 6am.

Comment: I discovered a shorter formula and I thought I should share:  (([Production Date]+[Production Time])-"12:00")-"12:00"